# Appium I am seeing error message after running the following Appium code

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium, appium

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Command duration or timeout: 610 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58' System info: host: 'INDC5WWGY1', ip: '10.135.161.85', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67' Session ID: eaffbafa14995946ea8e119fb1539160 Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver Capabilities [{platform=ANDROID, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=44.0.2403.119, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, hasTouchScreen=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678) at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:51) at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:268) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:526) at appium.My.main(My.java:38)

Comment: Below is code snippet:-

Answer (score 0):

Did you start your Appium server before running the test? If not, then please start your Appium server then run your script and it should work.